# How can i set more than one id in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 function in jquery like this :-

```
$('#age').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});

$('#phone').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});
```

this tow function is same to do .

so i need to mearge this tow function in one like :-

```
$('#phone') + $('#age').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#phone,#age').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

like this: just for demo sake: http://jsfiddle.net/2ASnz/

You can combine multiple selectors with a comma.

This link will give you more insight: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Hope this help `:)`

**code**

```
$('#phone,#age').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method.

Comment: Bruvo @undefined `:)` ruddy big Congrats on 60 K points! Great to see you as always!

Answer (score 1):

Give the two elements same class and select them by their class, then do same thing to both elements.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery generally works on collections. You can pass more than one selector expression separated by commas. This will work as you required.

```
$('#phone, #age').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `,` in your  selectors to have multiple selectors  [**Multiple Selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#phone,#age').on('keypress', function(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    return !(charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
});
```